# Export APNs certificate as a p12 file

Tags: apple-push-notifications, keychain, cer, p12

I'm trying to export the APNs certificate as a `.p12` file.

but, after I double click on the `.cer` file, I can't find it under "My Certificates", and I'm not allowed to export it as `.p12` file (but `.cer`, `.pem`, `p7b`).

why? I created this certificate on the same computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue seems to be with you private key. If private key associated with certificate is missing then it will not get displayed in keychain under "My certificates" sections. You can still see under all certificates.
Create a new certificate with new certificate signing request file and try to install it on mac. This may solve your problem.

Comment: Seriously thank you. This saved me HOURS. Really appreciate it.

Comment: What does private key missing mean? I created a new certificate signing request, uploaded it to the apple developer portal and downloaded the ".cer" certificate file. I doubelicked on it, but it still doesn't appear in 'My certificates'.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself. It seems that if in Keychain Access you try to export the Certificate from the All Items tab, it just tries to export the certificate without the key. When trying to export from the My Certificates tab, it worked as expected and I could export as .p12

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and decided I'd just let fastlane do the work: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pem/
It generated the correct files and I was on my way in less than 30 seconds!

Thanks Fastlane!